# Annoying Error on Quit

Tags: debugging

Emacs throws an error every time I use <kbd>C-g</kbd> to cancel a process. This is getting annoying.

```el
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
  read-from-minibuffer("Switch to buffer: " nil (keymap (keymap (11 . ivy-switch-buffer-kill)) keymap (36 . ivy-magic-read-file-env) (3 keymap (19 . ivy-rotate-sort) (1 . ivy-toggle-ignore) (15 . ivy-occur)) (67108903 . ivy-avy) (33554464 . ivy-restrict-to-matches) (15 . hydra-ivy/body) (22 . ivy-scroll-up-command) (prior . ivy-scroll-down-command) (next . ivy-scroll-up-command) (7 . minibuffer-keyboard-quit) (right . ivy-forward-char) (32 . self-insert-command) (18 . ivy-reverse-i-search) (19 . ivy-next-line-or-history) (remap keymap (describe-mode . ivy-help) (kill-ring-save . ivy-kill-ring-save) (kill-whole-line . ivy-kill-whole-line) (kill-line . ivy-kill-line) (scroll-down-command . ivy-scroll-down-command) (scroll-up-command . ivy-scroll-up-command) (end-of-buffer . ivy-end-of-buffer) (beginning-of-buffer . ivy-beginning-of-buffer) (kill-word . ivy-kill-word) (forward-char . ivy-forward-char) (delete-char . ivy-delete-char) (backward-kill-word . ivy-backward-kill-word) (backward-delete-char-untabify . ivy-backward-delete-char) (delete-backward-char . ivy-backward-delete-char) (previous-line . ivy-previous-line) (next-line . ivy-next-line)) (9 . ivy-partial-or-done) (10 . ivy-alt-done) (27 keymap (1 . ivy-read-action) (15 . ivy-dispatching-call) (111 . ivy-dispatching-done) (25 . ivy-insert-current-full) (105 . ivy-insert-current) (106 . ivy-yank-word) (114 . ivy-toggle-regexp-quote) (97 . ivy-toggle-marks) (16 . ivy-previous-line-and-call) (14 . ivy-next-line-and-call) (118 . ivy-scroll-down-command) (112 . ivy-previous-history-element) (110 . ivy-next-history-element) (10 . ivy-immediate-done) (13 . ivy-call)) (mouse-3 . ivy-mouse-dispatching-done) (mouse-1 . ivy-mouse-done) (down-mouse-1 . ignore) (13 . ivy-done)) nil ivy-history)
  ivy-read("Switch to buffer: " internal-complete-buffer :keymap (keymap (11 . ivy-switch-buffer-kill)) :preselect "SOP.org" :action ivy--switch-buffer-action :matcher ivy--switch-buffer-matcher :caller ivy-switch-buffer)
  ivy-switch-buffer()
  funcall-interactively(ivy-switch-buffer)
  #<subr call-interactively>(ivy-switch-buffer t nil)
  elmacro-record-command(#<subr call-interactively> ivy-switch-buffer nil nil)
  apply(elmacro-record-command #<subr call-interactively> (ivy-switch-buffer nil nil))
  call-interactively(ivy-switch-buffer nil nil)
  command-execute(ivy-switch-buffer)
```

Anybody knows what's happening over here?

Comment: Is the problem just `C-h v debug-on-quit` ?

Comment: Just to make @phils's suggestion explicit: `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit` should get rid of the backtrace in that case.

Comment: I recently had very similar with helm completion and it was time to completely rebuild my emacs add on. Using straight.el  I did a straight-rebuild-all. Some interface between candidates, buffers and the rest o the magic had broken down following a package update.